# matplotlib diagram background depending on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, background

I'm trying to plot some data and want to have a colored background depending on data.

In the following sample I want to have data1 and data2 on the left yaxis and data3 on right yaxis. This is working. But additionally I tried to colorize the background depending on data3.

How do I need to format the data to get it working?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as md

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

data1 = [51.2, 51.2, 51.2, 50.7, 50.7, 50.5, 50.4, 50.7, 50.6]
data2 = [46.5, 46.1, 46.2, 46.3, 46.4, 46.3, 46.2, 46.1, 45.5]
data3 = [ 0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0]

timestamps = [1524614516, 1524615134, 1524615587, 1524615910, 1524616235, 1524616559, 1524616866, 1524617189, 1524617511]
timestamps_ = [dt.utcfromtimestamp(x) for x in timestamps]

for data in (data1,data2):
    ax1.plot(timestamps_, data, marker='.', linestyle='-')
ax1.set_ylabel("degC")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(timestamps_, data3, marker='x', linestyle='-')
ax2.pcolor(ax2.get_xlim(), ax2.get_ylim(), zip(timestamps_, data3), cmap='RdGn', alpha=0.3) 
ax2.set_ylabel("ON OFF")       

ax1.set_title("Mytitle")
for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    tick.label1.set_rotation(35)
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tobias/workspace/python_pyplot_test/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    ax2.pcolor(ax2.get_xlim(), ax2.get_ylim(), zip(timestamps_, data3), cmap='RdGn', alpha=0.3) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5732, in pcolor
    X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5576, in _pcolorargs
C.shape, Nx, Ny, funcname))
TypeError: Dimensions of C (9, 2) are incompatible with X (2) and/or Y (2); see help(pcolor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use [`axvspan`s](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvspan.html):

[image]

One difference between using `axvspan` and `pcolor` is that the vertical span (rectangles) drawn by `axvspan` are unbounded in the `y`-direction while the `pcolor` rectangles are not. So if you use the `zoom` button to resize the plot, the `axvspan` rectangles will stretch to infinity (roughly speaking) while zooming out the `pcolor` rectangles will expose white areas. It's not a big deal, just thought you'd like to know.

---

Also note that if the vertical spans start at the first data point and extend to the next data point, then the last value in `data3` never gets used. (Nine data points make eight vertical spans). If, however, you center the vertical spans around the data points -- so each data point is in the center of a span, then all 9 values in `data3` can be used.

Uncomment the commented code below (and comment-out the current definition of `timestamps_left` and `timestamps_right`) to see the difference.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as md

def topydates(timestamps):
    return [dt.utcfromtimestamp(x) for x in timestamps]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

data1 = [51.2, 51.2, 51.2, 50.7, 50.7, 50.5, 50.4, 50.7, 50.6]
data2 = [46.5, 46.1, 46.2, 46.3, 46.4, 46.3, 46.2, 46.1, 45.5]
data3 = [ 0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0]

timestamps = np.array([1524614516, 1524615134, 1524615587, 1524615910,
                       1524616235, 1524616559, 1524616866, 1524617189, 1524617511])
timestamps_ = topydates(timestamps)

for data in (data1,data2):
    ax1.plot(timestamps_, data, marker='.', linestyle='-')
ax1.set_ylabel("degC")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(timestamps_, data3, marker='x', linestyle='-')

# if you want the axvspans to be centered around the data points
# widths = np.diff(timestamps)
# midpoints = timestamps[:-1] + widths/2.0
# timestamps_left = topydates(np.r_[timestamps[0]-widths[0]/2, midpoints])
# timestamps_right = topydates(np.r_[midpoints, timestamps[-1] + widths[-1]/2.0])
# if you uncomment the code above, then comment-out the line below:
timestamps_left, timestamps_right = timestamps_[:-1], timestamps_[1:]

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
for left, right, val in zip(timestamps_left, timestamps_right, data3):
    print(left, right)
    color = cmap(val)
    ax2.axvspan(left, right, facecolor=color, alpha=0.3)

ax2.set_ylabel("ON OFF")       

ax1.set_title("Mytitle")
for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    tick.label1.set_rotation(35)
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you unutbu for your help! The result is exactly what I tried to do. I'll use the commented code because it looks more beautiful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal solution to what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np


data3 = np.array([ 0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0])

x=np.arange(9)
xp,yp=np.meshgrid(x,data3)
xp=xp.astype(float)-0.5
bgcolor=np.ones(xp.shape)*data3[None,:]

plt.pcolor(xp,yp,bgcolor) 
plt.plot(x, data3, marker='x', linestyle='-')
```

I took out the second axis and all the tick stuff as they were not related to the problem itself.

Comment: Thank you anishtain4 for your suggestion, but I still don't know how to bring it together with the timestamps. I'll take the other solution from unutbu

Comment: The problem was that pcolor takes 2d array as input and your inputs are 1d. Note the line `xp=xp.astype(float)-0.5` I have to center the background color and the data. You can add it to unutbu's solution